# Merging Output into one text box from multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a username and password field which I need both inputs captured from the multiple text input boxes above and be merged into the username and password field meaning both username and password will be the same. but my challenge is merging the input from the multiple fields and this is what ive managed to do so far

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style>
    .flex{
        display: flex;
    }
    .otSc {
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: 16px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 1px 0px;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        outline: none;
    }
    .otSc:last-child{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .otpCont {
        padding: 10px 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="otpCont flex spaceBetween">
        <input id="maxCode" class="otSc" type="text" maxlength="1">
        <input class="otSc form-control" type="text" maxlength="1">
        <input class="otSc form-control" type="text" maxlength="1">
        <input class="otSc form-control" type="text" maxlength="1">
        <input class="otSc form-control" type="text" maxlength="1">
        <input class="otSc form-control" type="text" maxlength="1">
    </div>

    <p>what is typed at the top should be a merged output at the bottom</p>
    <div class="col-md-6 m-b-15" >
        <input id="maxVoucherCode" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="user merged input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 m-b-15" >
        <input id="maxVoucherCode" type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="pass merged input"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#maxVoucherCode").keyup(function() {
        var maxVoucherCode = $(this).val();
        $("#maxCode").val(maxVoucherCode);    
    });

    $("#maxCode").keyup(function() {
        var maxCode = $(this).val();
        $("#maxVoucherCode").val(maxCode);    
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll(".otSc").forEach(function(otpEl) {
        otpEl.addEventListener("keyup", backSp);
        otpEl.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
            var nexEl = this.nextElementSibling;
            nexEl.focus();
        })
    })

    function backSp(backKey) {
        if (backKey.keyCode == 8) {
            var prev = this.previousElementSibling.focus()
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: First of, ID **must be unique**. You cannot have duplicated `id="maxVoucherCode"`. Secondly, it's hard to understand, given the above what should go where and what is the expected result. What means: *"should be a merged output at the bottom"*? What *bottom*? Also, why the first input has no `form-control` class? Why do you mix jQuery and JavaScript? If you already use jQuery, isn't it simpler to stick to it? Or, instead of loading the entire library, why not stick to vanilla JS?

Comment: Use rather `nexEl?.focus();` to prevent errors when typing into the last code's input field. Same goes for `this.previousElementSibling?.focus()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Paste PIN into multiple input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190042/383904) - which handles many other things that are not handled well in the above code.

Comment: I apologize im still a beginner at this. Let me try and rephrase. The multiple inputs are more like an OPT style and when the person enters the 6 digit code into the 6 fields i need that input duplicated into username and password field which i will then post into my DB for processing. In short the username and password field will be hidden and only the input field for the digits will. be visible but in the background the username and password filed will capture the entry being inputted into the 6 fields merging it into one line of text in both username and password

Comment: specify name of input elements whose value must be combined and to which elements?

Comment: You don't need two separate input fields, just send the data to the backend as name="pin[]" and on the backend you'll have the array representation of the submitted PIN you can then use as username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. I would borrow the code from this answer: [Paste PIN into multiple input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190042/383904), and for the copying of the PIN into the two hidden input (password/username) I would additionally use `const PINValue = elsInput.reduce((s, el) => s + el.value, "");`

Example:

```js
// DOM utility functions:
const els = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelectorAll(sel);
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);


// Task: multiple inputs "field"

const elUN = el(`[name="username"]`);
const elPW = el(`[name="password"]`);

// Not sure why you would need this since are hidden, but there you go:
// elUN.addEventListener("input", () => { elPW.value = elUN.value; });
// elPW.addEventListener("input", () => { elUP.value = elPW.value; });


els(".pin").forEach((elGroup) => {

  const elsInput = [...els(`[name="pin[]"]`, elGroup)];
  const len = elsInput.length;
  
  const handlePaste = (ev) => {
    const clip = ev.clipboardData.getData('text');     // Get clipboard data
    const pin = clip.replace(/\s|-/g, "");             // Sanitize string
    const ch = [...pin];                               // Create array of chars
    elsInput.forEach((el, i) => el.value = ch[i]??""); // Populate inputs
    elsInput[Math.min(len, pin.length) - 1]?.focus();  // Focus input
  };

  const handleInput = (ev) => {
    const elInp = ev.currentTarget;
    const i = elsInput.indexOf(elInp);
    if (elInp.value && (i+1) % len) elsInput[i + 1]?.focus();  // focus next
    
    // Copy to UN/PW:
    const PINValue = elsInput.reduce((s, el) => s + el.value, "");
    elUN.value = PINValue;
    elPW.value = PINValue;
  };
  
  const handleKeyDn = (ev) => {
    const elInp = ev.currentTarget
    const i = elsInput.indexOf(elInp);
    if (!elInp.value && ev.key === "Backspace" && i) elsInput[i - 1]?.focus(); // Focus previous
  };
  
  
  // Add the same events to every input in group:
  elsInput.forEach(elInp => {
    elInp.addEventListener("paste", handlePaste);   // Handle pasting
    elInp.addEventListener("input", handleInput);   // Handle typing
    elInp.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDn); // Handle deleting
  });
  
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.pin>input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
Copy some of thise PINs into any of the below 6 PIN inputs:<br>
<code>123329</code><br>
<code>6 5 0 3 2 1</code><br>
<code>444-998</code><br>
<code>x1A23z</code>
<code>12</code>
<br>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="otpCont flex spaceBetween">

    <form>
      <h3>PIN:</h3>
      <div class="pin">
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required autofocus>
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required>
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required>
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required>
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required>
        <input type="text" name="pin[]" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" required>
      </div>

      <br> Hidden inputs demo:<br>
      <input type="text" name="username">
      <input type="text" name="password">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```